# stack bar chart both positive and negative

Tags: dc.js, stacked-chart

I have a dataset with an index based on multiple columns. The dataset has 5 attributes - columns A (positive number), B (negative number), C (positive number), D (negative number), E (positive)

Instead of key-value file format, a flat table is required.

I would like to get a stacked bar in the following format, but I have no clue how generate new dimensions to get the following chart by grouping some column A and B, columns C and D, and displaying column separately.

[image]

Any idea how to define these subgraphs in a stacked bar chart?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer at the moment. This is a matter of setting the [stackLayout](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/StackMixin.html#stackLayout__anchor) for the chart. You'll need to look at the options in [d3.stack](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stacks) and set them as shown in [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1375). It won't be the same layout but same idea. If you can't figure it out, please include a snippet in your question or fork [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/rL82bguk/1) and add your code.